# Batch file - Can't print out the text from java to .txt. by using batch programming

Tags: windows, batch-file

I met one problem that is I can't print whatever "println" inside java to a .txt file. All I get is an empty .txt file.

Here is the code. Any changes that I need to make this code works?

```
start cmd /c java Lumi_FTP "C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\Mohit_Task\AutomatedScript\3535-2D\lumi_ftp_3535-2D_settings_CW0%week%.ini" >"C:\test\Scriptlogs\3535-2D\log_DP_%fullstamp%_CW0%week%.txt"
```

Thanks for reviewing, comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://superuser.com/questions/338277/windows-cmd-batch-start-and-output-redirection:

Replace `>` with `^>`, e.g.:

```
start cmd /c java Lumi_FTP "C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\Mohit_Task\AutomatedScript\3535-2D\lumi_ftp_3535-2D_settings_CW0%week%.ini" ^> "C:\test\Scriptlogs\3535-2D\log_DP_%fullstamp%_CW0%week%.txt"
```

This happens for reasons I do not fully understand. I believe it escapes the `>` so that it applies to `start` instead of being part of the command string.

You could also not use `start`, but that may not be appropriate for your situation.

This is not related to the use of `java`.